# Is there any way in vscode to know where the current the file has been imported?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Are there any extensions/features in vs-code which could let me know where the current file is imported? I usually do a global search of the filename but it is time consuming when the file name is similar to any variable or there are similar named files.

Answer (score 14):

You can do a right-click on every function / variable or class. Then you choose "Find all references" to show where each function / variable or class is called.
For this you do not need an extension, because it is a standard feature of vscode

Comment: I checked that out and it is working for a few cases. I tried it out for a file in which the we are exporting a function using exports object at the bottom and I couldn't find its reference in the other file in which it was imported.

Answer (score 6):

*NO EXTENSION REQUIRED*

Yes, We can find the references of a file in VSCODE like this:
**Right-click** on the **file** and then **select** **Find References**.

VSCODE will show all the references/imports of the file.
[image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blus2.png)

Answer (score 1):

##### - find unused exports in project:

you can use [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iulian-radu-at.find-unused-exports) in vscode to find all unused exports

##### + find name references (e.g. used exports) in project:

click on name then press `shift+alt+F12`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right-click > Go to References (Shift + F12)
There is also an extension to change the appearance of how references show https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jrieken.references-plusplus

Answer (score 0):

If you are limiting your search to the current open workspace / folder, you can

1. do a search for 'import' using the magnifying glass or pressing ctrl+shift+s
2. open the results in editor by either clicking the link that says 'Open in editor' or by pressing alt+enter
3. In the document that opens, search for the name of your module.

In this way you will discover all of the imports that involve your module, regardless of whether you have used 'import mymodule' or 'from mymodule import myfunction' or anything else. I'm specifically thinking of how I'd structure a python project, but if you are using another language, you can alter the search in a way that works for the way your language does imports.